# Using threads in C to create an asynchronous timer

Tags: c, multithreading, timer, pthreads

I am not even sure if threads are a way to go with what I am trying to accomplish, but my intuition is telling me so.

I am implemeting a simple input in a while loop, character by character. If the time between the character input is greater than 2 seconds, the timeout should occur. The timeout is currently a simple printf in the main function.

This is my code:

```
typedef struct {
    clock_t startTime;
} timerStruct;

void *TimerThread(void *arg) {
    timerStruct timerThreadArgument = *((timerStruct *) arg);
    clock_t differenceTime;
    while(1) {
        differenceTime = clock() - timerThreadArgument.startTime;
        int millis = differenceTime * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        
        if (millis >= TIMEOUT_TIME) {
            return (void *) 2;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    pthread_t timerThreadId;
    void *threadReturn;
    char inputChar;
    
    printf("Input characters one by one or paste the string:\n");
    
    while (1) {
        timerStruct *timerThreadArgument = malloc(sizeof(*timerThreadArgument));
        timerThreadArgument->startTime = clock();
        
        pthread_create(&timerThreadId, NULL, TimerThread, timerThreadArgument);
        pthread_join(timerThreadId, &threadReturn);
        
        if ((int) threadReturn == 2) {
            printf("Timeout!\n");
        }
        
        scanf(" %c", &inputChar);
        
    }
}
```

The problem is, since I am using the pthread_join function, it blocks the main thread from executing and asking for input. I am aware why this is happening. If I don't use the pthread_join function, I am not going to be able to return the data from the thread, which is important because I wish to break the while loop if the timeout has occurred.

If anyone has an idea on how I could approach this, please share it.
Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Threads are not helpful for this. Sane use of threads is exclusively concerned with computation bound programs, not I/O and *especially* not I/O timeouts.

Comment: You should use `poll()` on standard input with a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with what you are attempting.  One of them is that stdio (ie. scanf) involves buffering; so you won't get a single character until a whole line is available.  The other is that what you have implemented is more akin to sleep() than a timeout.

In order to have direct control over tty input, you need to inform the device driver in the kernel of your desire.   The standard interface to this is tcgetattr, tcsetattr; which enables rather fine grained control of the tty.  The n?curses library is a little coarser, but much, much easier to use.

There are a lot of advantages to designing your system as a set of asynchronous services which provide events to one another.  In this, your keyboard handling might occupy a thread sending "Key Events" to some sort of dispatcher; and maybe another sending "Alarm Events" around to track timeouts.  This isn't a particularly easy pattern though.  Its value only comes to the fore in relatively large systems.

Some newer programming languages, Go for instance, have constructs specifically geared to this sort of architecture.  You might find it worthwhile to look at it, at least to get a flavour of how tidily it can be accomplished.